# Find elegant solution for finding same items that follow each other in two lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have multiple lists in list and I want to find out if any of them is at least a partial match.

Example:

```
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c"], ["z", "a", "b"], ["y", "b", "c"], ["z", "a"]]
```

The desired output should be:

```
["a", "b"] # because first and second list
["b", "c"] # because first and third list
["z", "a"] # because second and last list
```

❗The order and duplicated matters. So I cannot use `set`. it chance to have desired output like that: `["a", "b", "a"]`

I can probably loop over every item in 3 or more for cycles but for me is totally overkill and when I have 100 lists in list it will be really slow.

if exist any pandas or numpy function or something in Python that to do more efficiently I would appreciate it.

Comment: Should the matches be as large as possible or be at least to elements? E.g. `[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]` should match `["a", "b", "c"]` and not `["a", "b"]` and `["b", "c"]`?

Comment: Yes, it should be large as possible

Comment: How long are the matches going to be. From comments in seems match length is 2 or 3? Or does the match have the potential to be longer? Also, what are the potential items? More permutations than just single letters?

Comment: The maximum matches for one list can be around 30 following items.

Comment: Should `[["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["b", "a"]]` result in `[["a", "b"], ["b", "a"]]` or only one of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this isn't the highest-performance solution possible, but found a method that appears to work. Check how it works with your lists and drop a comment if it needs tweaking.

It combines the lists into a comma-delimited string then uses Regex to search for repeating sequences.

```
import re
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c"], ["z", "a", "b"], ["y", "b", "c"], ["z", "a"]]
search=re.compile(r'([a-z]{2,}).+?,?.+?\1') #
text=','.join([''.join(s) for s in list_of_lists])
i=0
matches=[]
results=[]
while len(text)>0:
    if result := search.search(text):
        if (span := tuple(x+i for x in result.span())) not in matches:
            matches.append(span)
            results.append(list(result.group(1)))
    text=text[1:]
    i+=1
results
```

Comment: I would change the appending to `results` to `results.append(list(result.group(1)))` to get the output OP wants. Other than that, this seems to work.

Comment: Good spot, thanks. I've edited the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Definitely, it works will see if it will be working on large sets :)